# Laravel view render and javascript?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-views

I have in my application a lot of generated reports with html tables, now I implemented with vuejs diagrams. But I can't get them rendered because they are in javacript.

```
$view = view('reports.single.print', ['stats' => $stats]);
$html = $view->render();
```

In normal browser mode everything is fine, but I need to get rendered html for print mode.

I tried with moving from bottom to `<head>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/app.js') }}"></script>`

but nothing changes.

My blade looks like:

```
<body>
@include('header')

HTML TABLE CONTENT

<diagram></diagram>

@include('footer')

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/app.js') }}">
</body>
```

Can I render somehow also javascript with `render()` method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try adding a closing tag (`</script>`).

Replace:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/app.js') }}">
```

with the following:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```